# how to return a address from a function and collect in main?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
main()
{
    int fd, retval, i;
    int ptr;
    char buff[1000];
    system("ps -A --no-headers -o pid>pid.txt");
    fd = open("pid.txt", O_RDONLY);
    retval = read(fd, buff, 1000);
    buff[retval] = '\0';
    int count= get_count(buff);
    ptr = get_each_pid(buff, count);
    for(i=0; i< count; i++)
    printf("%d \n", *(ptr+i));

}

int get_each_pid(char *pids, int count)
{
    int val, i, j=0, k=0,l=0;
    char temp[10];
    int *p= (void *)malloc(count);
    for(i=0; pids[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if(pids[i]!=' ')
        {
            temp[j]= pids[i];
            j++;
            if(pids[i+1]=='\n')
            {
                temp[j]='\0';
                val=atoi(temp);

                //  printf("int: %d \n", val);
                for(k=l; k<=l; k++)
                    *(p+k)=val;
                i++;
                l++;
                j=0;
            }
        }
    }
    return p;
}

int get_count(char *str)
{
int i, count=0;
    for(i=0; str[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if(str[i]=='\n')
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Here I want to get all the process ids in my system and want to open one by one. To acheive that I need to store all the pids in a txt file, convert each string into integer and store it in a array: Upto here the code if fine. The problem is I want to return the starting address to main function. Could anyone please check on this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does  your 2 nd for loop in get each pid function is doing

Comment: To return an `int *` you need to make your function return `int *`, not `int`. Also you malloc the wrong number of bytes (and may have further errors, I didn't check). `int *p = malloc(count * sizeof *p);`

Comment: `for(k=l; k<=l; k++)` only ever iterates once (since it starts and ends at `l`).

Comment: just define the function as int *get_each_pid(char *pids, int count)

Answer (score 0):

You should change the get_each_pid function prototype to:

```
int* get_each_pid(char *pids, int count)
```

since you are returning a pointer